PDF watermark is flipped when using Windows 10+ "Print to PDF" option
I am generating watermarked PDFs using the Print to PDF feature in Windows 10 or later, but I’m facing an issue where the watermark flips or appears mirrored when printed or viewed. I am using the iText7 library to add the watermark to the PDFs, and the following code is used for watermark generation:
try
{
    using var inputStream = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);
    using var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

    var writerProperties = password != null ? CreateEncryptedWriterProperties(password) : new WriterProperties();

    using var reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
    using var writer = new PdfWriter(outputStream, writerProperties);
    using var document = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);

    var pageCount = document.GetNumberOfPages();
    for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
    {
        var page = document.GetPage(i);
        var canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamAfter(), page.GetResources(), document);
        DrawWatermark(canvas, watermarkText, document, page);
    }

    document.Close();
    return outputStream.ToArray();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger?.LogError(ex, "Error watermarking PDF bytes");
    return null;
}


private void DrawWatermark(PdfCanvas canvas, string watermarkText, PdfDocument document, PdfPage page)
    {
        var pageSize = page.GetPageSize();
        var (pageWidth, pageHeight) = (pageSize.GetWidth(), pageSize.GetHeight());

        var dateText = _options.IncludeDate ? DateTime.Now.ToString(_options.DateFormat) : string.Empty;
        var font = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_options.FontPath) ? PdfFontFactory.CreateFont() : PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(_options.FontPath);

        var position = CalculateWatermarkPosition(watermarkText, dateText, pageWidth, pageHeight, _options.FontSize, font);

        ApplyWatermark(canvas, watermarkText, dateText, position, font, pageWidth, pageHeight);
    }

    private (float TextX, float TextY, float DateX, float DateY, float TextWidth, float DateWidth) CalculateWatermarkPosition(
        string watermarkText,
        string dateText,
        float pageWidth,
        float pageHeight,
        float fontSize,
        PdfFont font)
    {
        var textWidth = (font.GetWidth(watermarkText) * fontSize) / 1000;
        var dateWidth = (font.GetWidth(dateText) * (fontSize / 2)) / 1000;

        var centerX = pageWidth / 2f;
        var centerY = pageHeight / 2f;

        float verticalSpacing = fontSize / 4;

        return (
            TextX: centerX - textWidth / 2f,
            TextY: centerY,
            DateX: centerX - dateWidth / 2f,
            DateY: centerY - fontSize - verticalSpacing,
            TextWidth: textWidth,
            DateWidth: dateWidth
        );
    }
private void ApplyWatermark(
    PdfCanvas canvas,
    string watermarkText,
    string dateText,
    (float TextX, float TextY, float DateX, float DateY, float TextWidth, float DateWidth) position,
    PdfFont font,
    float pageWidth,
    float pageHeight)
{
    var centerX = pageWidth / 2f;
    var centerY = pageHeight / 2f;
    var angleInRadians = (float)(_options.RotationAngle * Math.PI / 180);

    canvas.SaveState();

    var gs = new PdfExtGState().SetFillOpacity(_options.Opacity);
    canvas.SetExtGState(gs);

    canvas.BeginText()
        .SetFontAndSize(font, _options.FontSize)
        .SetFillColor(_options.Color)
        .SetTextRenderingMode(PdfCanvasConstants.TextRenderingMode.FILL_STROKE);

    var cosAngle = (float)Math.Cos(angleInRadians);
    var sinAngle = (float)Math.Sin(angleInRadians);

    var tx = position.TextX - centerX;
    var ty = position.TextY - centerY;

    var finalX = centerX + (tx * cosAngle - ty * sinAngle);
    var finalY = centerY + (tx * sinAngle + ty * cosAngle);

    canvas.SetTextMatrix(
        cosAngle, sinAngle,
        -sinAngle, cosAngle,
        finalX, finalY
    )
    .ShowText(watermarkText);

    canvas.EndText()
        .RestoreState();
}

The issue appears to happen only with PDFs generated using the "Print to PDF" feature of Windows 10 or later. PDFs generated by other means do not exhibit this problem.



Are there any metadata tags, producer identifiers, or specific characteristics in the PDF structure I can look for? Is there a reliable way to check if a PDF uses a "top-down" coordinate system or has been transformed in a way that would require Y-coordinate adjustment?

PDFs aren't documents, they're files containing print instructions (PostScript) that can appear in any order. Print to PDF isn't exactly a feature, it's used to print to a PDF printer driver instead of an actual printer. It's the application that's doing the drawing etc though, so the print instructions depend on what the application is sending to the printer. The coordinate system can change.

I have an additional complication: the PDF files are generated on the client side (using tools like "Print to PDF" on Windows) and then uploaded to an MSSQL database. I don't have control over the generation process, only access to the uploaded files. Since I can’t normalize the files at the source, would you still recommend extracting and analyzing the PDF Producer metadata after retrieving the file from the database? If so, are there any common issues with PDFs generated by "Print to PDF" that I should specifically look for and address?

@KJ OK. I really appreciate your input, thanks

You use
var canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamAfter(), page.GetResources(), document);

to construct the PdfCanvas.
Consider using
var canvas = new PdfCanvas(page, true);

instead. The bool parameter value true causes iText to wrap the existing contents in a save-graphics-state/restore-graphics-state envelope.
(Depending on the exact way you want the watermark to appear, it might be advantageous to use page.SetIgnorePageRotationForContent with a matching parameter before that.)

Thank you for the suggestion! I was actually using this approach before I even knew the current issue existed. However, I had to switch to the current method (page.NewContentStreamAfter) because using it caused issues with PDFs containing scanned images. Specifically, the watermark would sometimes appear below the images instead of on top of them.

That is surprising as this construction under the hood also uses page.NewContentStreamAfter(). IMO you should go back to that approach and analyze the problems you encountered with it in detail.

I have switched back to var canvas = new PdfCanvas(page, true); It seems to be working fine so far. However, I must admit that I can’t fully recall the exact issue that made me switch to NewContentStreamAfter() earlier—it was three or four months ago. I’m certain there was some problem, though, possibly related to scanned-image PDFs or something similar. I’m testing this to see if I can replicate the issue or confirm it as resolved. I’ll update here if I encounter anything notable.

If you happen to come across an issue with that approach, please make that a question here on stack overflow and provide the example file.
